# SQL Replication doesn't clear CD caches on remote target

Tags: azure, paas, caching, setup

We have a multi-cd publishing situation I can use some help with.

We are in an Azure PAAS situation, with the CM and 1 CD server located in the US.  We also have a CD Server and SQL database in China (using Azure China/21 Vianet).  Due to the fault tolerance, we decided to use replication to move the data to China.  So we set up a publishing target in the US called web_china and can publish to that database.  We then use replication to copy the data from the US to China.

The issue is that the replication can take up to 5 minutes and by that time the publish:end:remote event has already been processed by the China CD server.  So even though the data is in the web_china database in China, due to caching (?) the changes are not visible.  If we publish the item a second time (since it is already in China), it appears on the site.

I have tried to add a task that runs in China and clears the cache on a regular basis.  It clears both the Html Cache, MVC Cache, and Rendering Parameters Cache.  However, even after running, the item is not visible in China.  I then tried to delete all Caches, but that brought the site to a grinding halt.

Is there another cache that I should clear to get the published changes to show up?

Or is the better idea to just convert to using Publishing Service, which is a much more fault-tolerant process.

Comment: have you seen this? https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/610106

Comment: Are you using publishing service?

Comment: No, we are trying to avoid adding new infrastructure.

Answer (score 1):

A great, fast supported way is documented [here](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/100/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/walkthrough--replicating-the-web-database-using-azure-active-geo-replication.html) using Azure SQL Geo Replication.
The idea is:

- The Sitecore Web DB is put in a geo replication group
- You need a new "Shared" DB that all Sitecore instances connect to - purely for the Event Queue, Properties, and Tasks tables.
- This way your content data is replicated with the power of Azure SQL, but cache clearing and other events can still happen.

Comment: That was our first thought.  However there is a legal requirement that the CD server reside in China.  Azure does not support geolocation to China. The database is being hosted by 21Vianet in China, so the best we could do is one way replication